# Como centralizar verticalmente dois elementos alinhados horizontalmente em direções opostas?

Tags: css

Eu estou criando uma *topnav* que contém duas `div`, de tamanhos diferentes. O objetivo é uma delas ficar na esquerda e a outra na direita. Para isso, eu fiz o seguinte código, seguindo essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22301620/11679204):

```html
<nav id="topNav">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <img src="./images/mini_logo.png"/>
        <a href="">Disciplinas</a>
        <a href="">Professores</a>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <img src="./images/profile.png"/>
        <a href="logout">Sair</a>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</nav>
```

O problema é que, como eu disse anteriormente, ambas as DIVs possuem tamanhos diferentes (por conta das imagens nelas). Então agora, eu preciso centralizá-las verticalmente. E esse é o problema.

Aparentemente, qualquer solução que use `display: flex`, `position: relative`, etc, acaba retirando o alinhamento horizontal dos elementos. O que eu faço?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o motivo do desalinhamento é o tamanho diferente das imagens, a solução mais simples é fazer com que as imagens tenham o mesmo tamanho, utilizando as propriedades `width` e `height` na folha de estilos. Inclusive acho que essa opção torna a interface mais esteticamente agradável.

Se o tamanho diferente das imagens for *intencional*, pode utilizar *flexbox* em vez de *floats* para controlar não somente o alinhamento horizontal, mas também o vertical.

Para isso basta utilizar a propriedade `align-items` em cada subseção do menu.

Um exemplo:

```css
.top-nav {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

.top-nav-section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.top-nav-section--right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.top-nav-section > *:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.square {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #00f;
}
.square--big {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<nav class="top-nav">
    <div class="top-nav-section">
        <span class="square"></span>
        <a href="#">Disciplinas</a>
        <a href="#">Professores</a>
    </div>
    <div class="top-nav-section top-nav-section--right">
        <span class="square square--big"></span>
        <a href="#">Sair</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Como as imagens do exemplo não foram fornecidas utilizei quadrados criados utilizando a tag _span_ para facilitar.